# "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token" (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement

so I'm getting error in line 37 with the else if, and I don't have any idea why this is happening.
The IDE says: "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token".
Thanks.

```
package jogo;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     Random rand = new Random();
     String name;
     System.out.println("Welcome to the game! Enter your name.");
     name = in.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Welcome " +name);
     System.out.println("Which direction you will walk? ( W, A, S D )");
     String comando = in.nextLine();
     
     if(comando.equals("W"));
        System.out.println("You decided to walk through the vast forest.");
        System.out.println("And suddenly a goblin appeared, what are you going to do? ( A = Attack and C = Run )");
        comando = in.nextLine();
        if(comando.equals("A"));
            if(rand.nextInt(100) <= 75)
        {
            System.out.println("You won the battle.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You lost the battle.");
            {       
            else if(comando.equals("C")); 
            System.out.println("You ran away from the battle.");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if` structures are *very* broken, and combined with inconsistent indentation I can't tell which `else` is meant to go with which `if`.  Remove the semi-colons from the `if` statements, consistently wrap the `if` and `else` code blocks in curly braces, and use consistent indentation.  Currently you and the compiler are reading the code differently, which is leading to your confusion.

Comment: It is really difficult to deduct what you are trying to do from your code. The compilation error is due to `else if(comando.equals("C")); ` line. The `else if` is present without any 'if'. Although fixing this will lead to successful compilation, there seems to be some logical errors. For ex: `if(comando.equals("A"));`, placing a semi colon just after an `if` statement does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your program the Syntax for `if`, `else if`, and `else` is not correct. Here is your code with right Syntax.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    String name;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game! Enter your name.");
    name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Welcome " +name);
    System.out.println("Which direction you will walk? ( W, A, S D )");
    String comando = in.nextLine();
 
    if(comando.equals("W")){
        System.out.println("You decided to walk through the vast forest.");
        System.out.println("And suddenly a goblin appeared, what are you going to do? ( A = Attack and C = Run )");
        comando = in.nextLine();
        if(comando.equals("A")){
            if(rand.nextInt(100) <= 75){
                System.out.println("You won the battle.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("You lost the battle.");
            }
        }
        else if(comando.equals("C")){
            System.out.println("You ran away from the battle.");
        }
    }
```

Also check [Java Conditions and If Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There were few errors in the code like after some if conditions you have put semi-colon(;) and even there were some error of brackets. I have edited the code and now its working properly.

```
package jogo;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    String name;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game! Enter your name.");
    name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Welcome " +name);
    System.out.println("Which direction you will walk? ( W, A, S D )");
    String comando = in.nextLine();
    
    if (comando.equals("W")){
        System.out.println("You decided to walk through the vast forest.");
        System.out.println("And suddenly a goblin appeared, what are you going to do? ( A = Attack and C = Run )");
        comando = in.nextLine();
        
        if(comando.equals("A")){
            if(rand.nextInt(100) <= 75){
            System.out.println("You won the battle.");
        }
            else{
                System.out.println("You lost the battle.");
            }
        
        }
        
        else if(comando.equals("C")){
            System.out.println("You ran away from battle");
        }
    }
        
    }
    
}
```